# Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime exception in method execution

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, exception

I am having the above exception come up when executing my method (code below):

```
Sub loadDates(ByVal newDate As Date)

    Dim dayCount As Integer = 0

    conn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    ds = New DataSet("Holiday")
    sql = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Holiday", conn)

    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT date FROM Holiday", conn)
    conn.Open()
    da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "Holiday")
    da.Fill(ds, "Holiday")

    Dim tblHoliday As DataTable
    tblHoliday = ds.Tables("Holiday")

    For Each row As DataRow In tblHoliday.Rows
        If Not row Is Nothing Then
            For items As Integer = 0 To tblHoliday.Rows.Count Step 1
                Dim dateValue As Date = row.Item(0)
                If newDate = dateValue Then
                    dayCount += 1
                End If
                Exit For
            Next
        End If
    Next

    conn.Close()

    If newDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or newDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
        dayCount = 2
    End If

    For days As Integer = dayCount To 0 Step -1
        Dim dropDates As Date = New Date(newDate.Year, newDate.Month, newDate.Day - days)
        ddDate.Items.Add(dropDates.ToShortDateString())
    Next
End Sub
```

I've narrowed down the problem to being within the For Each loop in the method, when I enter in a date and it skips over the loop it works without a problem. When it has to go through the loop it crashes on the line:

```
Dim dropDates As Date = New Date(newDate.Year, newDate.Month, newDate.Day - days)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `newDate.Day - days` is not negative or 0? Actually you can call `AddDays(-1*days)` on `newDate` to achieve the same result, and it will safely go to previous month if needed

Comment: Yes, what is the value of newDate for the test case?

Comment: oh sorry, the newdate is today's date minus one so for example it would be #07/09/2014#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract the days from the date instead of from the day component, that way the day compontent doesn't get out of range:

```
Dim dropDates As Date = New Date(newDate.Year, newDate.Month, newDate.Day).AddDays(-days)
```

If `newDate` doesn't have any time component component that you are getting rid of by using that `Date` constructor, you can just use `newDate` directly:

```
Dim dropDates As Date = newDate.AddDays(-days)
```

Comment: What's interesting is that if this were JavaScript, it would actually allow that!